# Physical Back Button Behaviour with react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have tab navigation and I need to create a single back button for all of the screens.
For now, I am creating a back button in all of the screens and calling `navigation.goBack()` from all of them when back pressed because the `navigation` object is available inside screens only.

Is there a way where I can create a separate back button and then call `navigation.goBack()` to whichever the current screen is in the navigator?

Also, I have nested navigation also like stack navigator inside tab navigator, so I need to call the deepest navigator's go back function.

for example,

```
TabNavigator
  tab1: screen1
  tab2: stackNavigator
          stack1: screen2
          stack2: screen3
```

and when I press the back button on screen 3, I should navigate to screen 2, not tab 1.
Like the physical back-button behaves in react-navigation in android OS.

Comment: what are trying to achieve is similar to the back button on the header left of the navigation, right? you want to create a button which will appear on all the screens like the back button  !!

Comment: yes right, I have a header and it contains a back button.

Comment: But we don't have back button in tab navigation